# How to import data from custom template tag to javascript? Django

Tags: javascript, json, django, parsing

How to escape js on a custom template tag?

In my custom_tags.py I have registered a simple tag which simply takes data from firebase in form of array of dictionary. I want to pass this array directly to my JavaScript but doing so gives me error.

my custom_tags.py -

```
@register.simple_tag
def getMessageData():
message_data = []
data = database.child('ChatMessages').get()
for task in data.each():
    message_data.append(task.val())
return dumps(message_data)
```

in my js -

```
messageData = JSON.parse("{% getMessageData %}");
```

This gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at (index):23` error.

I tried debugging value by `var temp2 = "{% getMessageData %}"` so I found its value to be [image]

So basically I need some way to use escapejs on my custom template tag.. Its easy to do on values passed through rendering but with `{% template_tag_name|escapejs %}` gives error as it considers escapejs a part of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is convert all to the string and then use javascript replaceAll() to convert quot to double inverted commas.

Something like

```
let getmessageData  = [{"&quot;hello&quot; : &quot;message&quot;"}]
getmessageData = getmessageData[0].replaceAll("&quot;",'"')
console.log(getmessageData);
// Output : "hello" : "message"
```

Once you get a JSON you can use that in your parse method.

I hope this may help.